# Links wont worked when using position:fixed on tumblr

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a custom tumblr theme, but whenever I put a link in a div that has postion: fixed , the link becomes unclickable and is treated as normal text.

This is where the link is not working:

```
<div id="sidebar"><center>
    <p id="avap">
    <br><b>EARTH-BEETLE</b>
    <br><a href="earth-beetle.tumblr.com"><img src="{PortraitURL-64}" /></a>
    </p>  
      <a href="http://chickensmoothie.com">test link</a>
    </center></div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
 #sidebar {
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    }
#tagp {
    background-color: #87DEBE;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 490px;
    left: 35px;
    border-color: #208560;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
}
#avap {
    background-color: #87DEBE;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Works fine. You will need to post full code.

Comment: My guess is that the container is behind another one: try increasing the z-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the z-index to 5 worked, thanks!